# Expressjs Error- ReferenceError: cors is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am creating An ExpressJs Backend when I run this backend I am getting this error.

```
app.use(cors())
    ^

ReferenceError: cors is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\hp\Desktop\Entri\kanba\index.js:5:5)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1256:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1310:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:960:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47
```

I am sending a get request from postman. I expect response from backend but what I get it an error.

Comment: You need to install the [cors package](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html) and include it into your file

Comment: You must import cors library

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems like you have not installed the middleware called `cors`.

Run this command in your project's terminal to install `cors`

> npm install cors

Now you should import the cors package in your application

> const cors = require('cors')

For more information, please checkout [express cors documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html)

Hope this works. Have a good day!

Comment: This alone won't fix OP's error. Also, this question has been asked and answered (many times) before

Comment: I installed the package but the error is still there

Comment: @AnjuJacob I forgot to mention, you should import the package in your application as well. I'll update my answer

Comment: @Phil The OP seems to be new to Stackoverflow, so it's okay

Comment: Phil, sachin Titus The issue is solved. Thanks for your Answers.